# Java DataStax Cassandra exception error

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am getting this error on insert in java. Is there a way to prepare 
the insert for the driver error?

Error:

> Exception in thread "main"     com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 4 or 0 byte int (10)

```
List<Flight> flightList = ProcessFlightsCSV.processFlights("flights_from_pg.csv");

for (Flight flight : flightList) {

    System.out.println(flight);

    Insert query = QueryBuilder.insertInto("flights")
            .value("id", flight.getId())
            .value("year", flight.getYear())
            .value("fl_date", flight.getFlDate())
            .value("airline_id", flight.getAirlineId())
            .value("carrier", flight.getCarrier())
            .value("fl_num", flight.getFlNum())
            .value("origin_airport_id", flight.getOriginAirportId())
            .value("origin", flight.getOrigin())
            .value("origin_city_name", flight.getOriginCityName())
            .value("origin_state_abr", flight.getOriginStateAbr())
            .value("dest", flight.getDest())
            .value("day_of_month", flight.getDayOfMonth())
            .value("dest_city_name", flight.getDestCityName())
            .value("dest_state_abr", flight.getDestStateAbr())
            .value("dep_time", flight.getDepTime())
            .value("arr_time", flight.getArrTime())
            .value("distance", flight.getDistance());

    session.execute(query);

}
```

Comment: Yuor solution resolved the original issue.  Thank you. !

Answer (score 0):

1. Hopefully you have proper session before executing this query.
2. Update your session.execute(query.toString());

Comment: running it, I receive a different exception Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid STRING constant (2012/11/11) for "fl_date" of type timeuuid

Comment: yeah. Thats good. So you are moving ahead. This error suggest that format is not what is expected. So you need to convert the date from String format to long and pass it to Cassandra.